# Singleton lazy loading pattern best practice to store session objects

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to use singleton pattern to store session objects for my web application. I need advise if this is the most efficient way of doing it.

My solution is based on the research i have done on Jon Skeet's work around this topic.

```
    private const string SESSION_SINGLETON = "SINGLETON";

    private static readonly Lazy<SessionManager> lazy = new Lazy<SessionManager>(() => new SessionManager());

    public static SessionManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            SessionManager instance;

            if (null == HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_SINGLETON])
            {
                instance = lazy.Value;
                HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_SINGLETON] = instance;
            }
            else
            {
                instance = (SessionManager)HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_SINGLETON];
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private SessionManager()
    {
    }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string OrganisationId { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(SESSION_SINGLETON);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the instance stored in the session? What's the point there when you already have a static instance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs to code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com